# Inotifywait won't run

Tags: bash, centos7, inotifywait

inotifwait won't run command

"Setting up watches.
Watches established" is output, script just exit

```
 #!/bin/bash

while $(inotifywait -e  modify,close_write /home/centos/test.txt);
do
  touch /home/centos/log.txt
done
```

but when i modify test.txt log.txt is not created

Tried this version:

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -e modify,close_write /home/centos/test.txt |
while read output; do
  touch /home/centos/log.txt;
done
```

tried this also:

```
inotifywait -e modify,close_write /home/centos/test.txt |
while read -r filename event; do
  echo "test"        # or "./$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding `-m /folder`